# Eclipse juno - Unable to view classpath variable page under preferences

Tags: android, eclipse

I get the following error

```
 Unable to create the selected preference page.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I navigate to Eclipse preferences->Java->Build path->Class path variable.I did try cleaning the project and restarting eclipse.Once I do that it works, after building the project again I am getting the same error.Im working on android project with ADT 23.0.

Here is my error log

> !MESSAGE Unable to create the selected preference page. !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.buildpath.BuildPathSupport$JUnitPluginDescription.getSourceLocation(BuildPathSupport.java:112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.buildpath.BuildPathSupport$JUnitPluginDescription.getSourceBundleLocation(BuildPathSupport.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.buildpath.JUnitHomeInitializer.initializeSource(JUnitHomeInitializer.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.buildpath.JUnitHomeInitializer.initialize(JUnitHomeInitializer.java:31)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathVariable(JavaCore.java:3251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.VariableBlock.refresh(VariableBlock.java:409)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.VariableBlock.(VariableBlock.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preferences.ClasspathVariablesPreferencePage.(ClasspathVariablesPreferencePage.java:50)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1340)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:377)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:709)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:705)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:65)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace.?

Comment: I am sorry I dont find any stacktrace.The only error I get is Java.Lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Open ErrorLog view form 'Window->Show View' and select Double click on your Error it will open one dialog with stackTrace.

Comment: Got the error log inside help->Installation details->Configuration->Error log

Answer (score 0):

From [Bug 364628](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364628):

> If a plus sign ('+') exists in Eclipse's path (e.g. "C:\Apps\Eclipse\3.7+SDK\eclipse.exe"), opening the Classpath Variables preferences page (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables) causes the following error:
>
> ```
> Unable to create the selected preference page.
>  java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```
>
> Removing the plus sign from the path fixes the issue.

Comment: There is no + plus in my path to Eclipse .. E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse

Comment: I have changed the path as E:\adt still I get the same error

Answer (score -1):

Just confirming I have the same issues. Plus unable to run any Junit tests.

I downloaded latest Android SDK w Eclipse along with the latest JDK.
I uninstalled, deleted prior existing directories.

I'm working on a Windows 7 laptop 64 bit.

I installed adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip in C:\Android.

In an attempt to find what could be going wrong, I modified all pertinent settings
such that I do not see any references to c:\users...
e.g.

```
   Pointing ANDROID_SDK_HOME , ECLIPSE_HOME, HOME =C:\Android\Home
   -Duser.home=C:\Android\Home
   -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Android\Home\Temp
```

(See Eclipse->Help->About Eclipse->Installation details->Configuration)